# E006 Not Found Error: in scala sbt jacoco

Tags: scala, unit-testing, sbt, jacoco

I am trying to write some tests for my code in scala
the problem is everytime i try to run jacoco with sbt I am getting all kinds of errors.

I am using VSCode if that has anything to do with it

This is a code snippet of the test

```
package model

import org.scalatest.Wordspec
import org.scalatest.matchers.should.Matchers._
import model._

class fieldSpec extends WordSpec with Matchers {

  "A Field" when {
    "not set any value" should {
      val emptyField = Field(0)
      "have value 0" in {
        emptyField.value should be(0)
      }
```

This is my build.sbt

```
val scala3Version = "3.1.1"

lazy val root = project
  .in(file("."))
  .settings(
    name := "MADN",
    version := "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT",

    scalaVersion := scala3Version,
    libraryDependencies += "org.scalameta" %% "munit" % "0.7.29" % Test,
    libraryDependencies += "org.scalactic" %% "scalactic" % "3.2.11",
    libraryDependencies += "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "3.2.11" % "test"
  )
```

When I am trying to run sbt jacoco I get this error message as an output

```
[error] -- [E006] Not Found Error: C:\Software-Engineering\MADN\src\test\scala\model\fieldSpec.scala:7:24
[error] 7 |class fieldSpec extends WordSpec with Matchers {
[error]   |                        ^^^^^^^^                                                                                                                                 
[error]   |                        Not found: type WordSpec                                                                                                                 
[error] -- [E006] Not Found Error: C:\Software-Engineering\MADN\src\test\scala\model\fieldSpec.scala:7:38                                                                   
[error] 7 |class fieldSpec extends WordSpec with Matchers {                                                                                                                 
[error]   |                                      ^^^^^^^^                                                                                                                   
[error]   |                                      Not found: type Matchers                                                                                                   
[error] -- [E008] Not Found Error: C:\Software-Engineering\MADN\src\test\scala\model\fieldSpec.scala:9:12
[error] 9 |  "A Field" when {
[error]   |  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^                                                                                                                                                 
[error]   |value when is not a member of String - did you mean ("A Field" : String).wait?                                                                                   
[error] -- [E006] Not Found Error: C:\Software-Engineering\MADN\src\test\scala\model\fieldSpec.scala:11:23
[error] 11 |      val emptyField = Field(0)                                                                                                                                 
[error]    |                       ^^^^^                                                                                                                                    
[error]    |                       Not found: Field                                                                                                                         
[error] -- [E008] Not Found Error: C:\Software-Engineering\MADN\src\test\scala\model\fieldSpec.scala:12:21
[error] 12 |      "have value 0" in {
[error]    |      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^                                                                                                                                         
[error]    |      value in is not a member of String                                                                                                                        
[error] -- [E008] Not Found Error: C:\Software-Engineering\MADN\src\test\scala\model\fieldSpec.scala:15:19
[error] 15 |      "not be set" in {
[error]    |      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^                                                                                                                                           
[error]    |      value in is not a member of String                                                                                                                        
[error] -- [E006] Not Found Error: C:\Software-Engineering\MADN\src\test\scala\model\fieldSpec.scala:20:26                                                                  
[error] 20 |      val nonEmptyField = Field(2)                                                                                                                              
[error]    |                          ^^^^^                                                                                                                                 
[error]    |                          Not found: Field                                                                                                                      
[error] -- [E008] Not Found Error: C:\Software-Engineering\MADN\src\test\scala\model\fieldSpec.scala:21:26
[error] 21 |      "return that value" in {
[error]    |      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^                                                                                                                                    
[error]    |      value in is not a member of String                                                                                                                        
[error] -- [E008] Not Found Error: C:\Software-Engineering\MADN\src\test\scala\model\fieldSpec.scala:24:15
[error] 24 |      "be set" in {
[error]    |      ^^^^^^^^^^^                                                                                                                                               
[error]    |      value in is not a member of String                                                                                                                        
[error] 9 errors found
[error] 9 errors found                                                                                                                                                      
[error] (Test / compileIncremental) Compilation failed
[error] Total time: 7 s, completed 06.04.2022 14:29:46
```

I also included the plugin at project/plugins.sbt

```
addSbtPlugin("com.github.sbt" % "sbt-jacoco" % "3.4.0")
```

My tests are in the following directory:
src>test>scala>model>fieldSpec.scala

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I was able to fix it by using **AnyWordSpec** instead of just **WordSpec**
and also by deleting the following line out of my build.sbt

```
libraryDependencies += "org.scalameta" %% "munit" % "0.7.29" % Test,
```